# Music Discord bot using DiscordJS not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, audio

I'm making my own discord bot using Discord.JS and I wanted to make it be able for you to say "!music" along with a link to a youtube video for it to play, but after testing over and over with many tweaks, I somehow made it stop working. I checked and everything else about the bot works, just not the music part.

> Note:
>   the command is just the string of the first part of the message, arg1 is the first argument
>   and the bot is Discord.client();

```
if(command === '!music') {
    var link = arg1
    const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
    const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1 };
    const broadcast = bot.createVoiceBroadcast();

    bot.voiceChannel.join()
      .then(connection => {
        const stream = ytdl(arg1, { filter : 'audioonly' });
        broadcast.playStream(stream);
        const dispatcher = connection.playBroadcast(broadcast);
      })
      .catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: I'm using discord.js, also I have no idea why my gist died

Comment: I reuploaded the gist https://gist.github.com/kittrz/34b39a0674bd25d99736a522035df852

Comment: Same thing, could you just add the constructor for the application into the question using an [edit] too?

Comment: Have you installed the audio lib (node-opus) ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong, there was a single curly bracket that made it do the if statements of some commands when you do a different command, so I fixed that and now I'm in a new problem where it will say that FFmpeg is not found, I have actually installed it, it just doesn't seem to see that it is installed.